# Access an array item in Perl after generating that array

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Hello I want to access an specific array item based in a condition previously checked. I leave the code here:

```
elsif (scalar(@{$boss->bosses}) > 1) {
  foreach my $pa (@{$boss->bosses}) {
    my $p = My::Model::Group->new(id => $pa->group_id);
    push(@$groups, $p);
    $valid_pass = 1 if ($pa->checkPassword($self->param('password')));
  }  
  if ($valid_pass) {    
    my $pa_id = $pa->id;
    my $pa_partner_id = $pa->group_id;
  }
  else {
  }
}
```

What I want to do is, if that if in the array that comes, I check if the password is correct, so if it's correct, then I want to take the id and the group_id of the array item to use it in a function to be able to log them in.

Comment: What is the question? What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @ceving: The OP wants to find the value of `$pa` for which `$valid_pass` is 1 so that they can use it to extract further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is doing two things at once: producing a list of `My::Model::Group` objects in `@$groups`, and finding the first boss whose password checks out.

I suggest that you split them up into two clear operations, and the `List::Util` modules `first` operator is ideal for the second task

Here's how it would look. I've extracted the result of the method call `$boss->bosses` into a variable `$bosses` to avoid repeated calls to the method

Note that you don't need to apply `scalar` to an array when checking its size. The `>` and all the other comparators impose scalar context anyway

I've taken much of my code from your question, and I'm a little concerned that you extract values for `$pa_id` and `$pa_partner_id` and then just discard them. But I imagine that you know what you really want to do here

```
use List::Util 'first';

my $bosses = $boss->bosses;

if ( ... ) {
    ...;
}
elsif ( @$bosses > 1 ) {

    @$groups = map { My::Model::Group->new( id => $_->group_id ) } @$bosses;

    my $password = $self->param( 'password' );
    my $pa       = first { $_->checkPassword( $password ) } @$bosses;

    if ( $pa ) {    
        my $pa_id         = $pa->id;
        my $pa_partner_id = $pa->group_id;
    }
    else {
        ...;
    }
}
```